# Некорректно работает redirect в Django на Raspberry PI

Tags: python, django

Имею рабочий Django-проект, который работает корректно под Ubuntu. Но на малинке странно работают редиректы. Вместо того, чтобы перенаправить пользователя на на нужную страницу, происходит перенаправление по адресу `some_addr%2Csome_addr:0/some_page`. Код редиректа:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
```

В чем может быть дело? Использую nginx 1.2.1 и gunicorn 0.14.5.
Та же проблема наблюдается с использованием декоратора `@login_requored('/signin')`

Comment: А что у вас в `next` хранится? Случайно не `some_addr%2Csome_addr:0/some_page`?

Comment: в next у меня хранится url вида '/some_page' или просто редирект наглавную '/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение на самом деле оказалось простым и внезапным. В конфигах nginx в строку
    `proxy_set_header Host      $host;`
необходимо добавить `:$server_port` 
 в итоге получается:
`proxy_set_header Host      $host:$server_port;`
Так же рекомендую установить одну из последних версий nginx.